# How to extend a theme in codemirror 6

Tags: codemirror-6

I'm using the `@codemirror/theme-one-dark` theme with codemirror 6 and I'm trying to figure out how to extend the theme. I mostly just want to increase the font size… any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I change the font size in codemirror 6 like this:

```
const extensions = [
    EditorView.theme({
        "&": { height: "100%" },
        '.cm-content': {
            fontSize: '16px'
        },
        '.cm-scroller': {

        },
    }),
];
```

then add the extension to codemirror:

```
const state = EditorState.create({
    doc: ytext.toString(),
    extensions: [
        basicSetup,
        extensions,
    ]
});
```

works for me.